# Unable to see the menu in xterm

Tags: xterm

Not sure what the deal is, but I can't see the menu in xterm when I <kbd>Ctrl+Right Click</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Left Click</kbd>.

My `.Xresources` file is pretty generic; nothing fancy, so I don't think that's the problem.


[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture could be interpreted in either of these ways:

- the geometry specified is too general, causing the menus to be too small (see [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#tiny_menus)), or
- you're using Ubuntu, which has a longstanding defect in their graphics (see [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compiz_bugs))